# How to save variables with onCleanup in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a Matlab script which runs on a cluster. If the time exceeds some timepoint it gets killed. I want to use onCleanup to save some (or all) variables before the script gets killed.

I have tried the following:

```
function [] = test
    ita = 5;
    finishup = onCleanup(@() save('test.mat','ita'));
    pause(7200);
    disp('done')
    exit
end
```

I thinkt the variable "ita" is killed before onCleanup is executed, it does not find that variable. The same appears if I turn the function into a script.

```
ita = 5;
finishup = onCleanup(@() save('test.mat','ita'));
pause(7200);
disp('done')
exit
```

How can I do it right?

Of course if I use onCleanup inside a function then it is executed as soon as function stops (e.g. ctrl+c). If I use a script then onCleanup is executed only when Matlab exits.

Comment: This really isn't the designed behavior of `onCleanup`. From MATLAB's documentation: "Your cleanup routine should never rely on variables that are defined outside of that routine." This means, as you have discovered, local variables cannot be used in a cleanup function. Do you know for sure that `onCleanup` will be called if the function is killed? I would be surprised if it did, in which case, this would not be the solution you were looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't exactly recommend this ... but it is a solution to your problem.  Set `ita` to be `global` then use a subfunction call to do the cleanup/MAT file saving.  This way `ita` is in scope.

This worked when either the function completed or if I hit Ctrl+C during the pause.

```
function [] = test()
    global ita
    ita = 5;
    finishup = onCleanup(@() cleanMe());
    pause(7200);
    disp('done')

function cleanMe()
global ita
save('test.mat','ita')
```